# How do I fix the align_image_stack error: "No valid distortion data found in lens database"?

Tags: lens, hugin, image-alignment

I am using Hugin's [align_image_stack --distortion](https://wiki.panotools.org/Align_image_stack) as a first step before median filtering.

Unfortunately, it says `No valid distortion data found in lens database`

I tried with both a Nikon D5300 and a Nexus 5, both fairly popular products, same message.

**Question**: How to add the data to this "lens database", so that me and others don't get this message in the future?

Comment: https://wiki.panotools.org/Fulla (in particular the "External Links" section) might be a good starting point for finding the answer, although some of the links are now dead.

Answer (score 2):

Hugin used to use the [lensfun](http://lensfun.sourceforge.net/) database. But [the 2015 version of Hugin's release notes](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/hugin-2015.0.0/en.shtml) state:

> **Lens database**
>
> Hugin now has its own camera and lens database, and hugin_lensdb is the maintenance tool.
>
> Lens data is automatically added to the database when stitching a project file from hugin. Data can also be manually added to the database from hugin and from Calibrate_Lens_GUI.
>
> Lens data can be applied to a project in the same manner as previously, in the Photos tab, select an image with right mouse to bring up the context menu and select Lens → Load lens from lens database.
>
> For database maintenance see `hugin_lensdb -h`, or [`man hugin_lensdb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/hugin_lensdb.1.html) (Linux and OSX) for details on usage.

On my OSX installation of the 2018 version of Hugin, the calibrate_len_gui.app is in the Applications/Hugin folder, next to Hugin.app, HuginStitchProject.app, and PTBatcherGUI.app.  hugin_lens_db lives in the usual Hugin.app packaged Contents/MacOS folder, with aliases in the Hugin/tools_mac folder (outside the package).